# Keybound Button with screen switching in Kivy language

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I need to make a `Button` that when the enter button is pressed allows me to return to a `Screen` in the `.kv` language. Here is what I have in Python:

```
def build(self):
    button = Button()
    start(Enter, button)
    bind(on_press = partial(sm.setter('current'), (sm, 'MenuScreen')))
```

How do I make a `Button` that allows me to return to a page when the 'Enter' key is pressed in .kv / the kivy lanaguage?

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a weird syntax you have up there and you talk about "Enter key" although the code obviously does something completely different, so I think you want just this little piece:

```
<Enter>:
    on_press: sm.current = 'MenuScreen'
```

These lines require an additional class `Enter` to exist i.e. you wouldn't do this (and I'm confused by that line):

```
start(Enter, button)
```

but you would do for example this:

**.py**

```
class Enter(Button):
    pass

class My(App):
    def build(self):
        pass
```

**.kv**

```
ScreenManager:
    id: sm
    Screen:
        name: 'OtherScreen'
        Enter:

    Screen:
        name: 'MainScreen'

<Enter>:
    on_press: sm.current = 'MainScreen'
```